# compare two ip with C#

Tags: c#, ip

How I can compare two IP address?

```
string ip1 = "123.123.123.123";
string ip2 = "124.124.124.124";
```

I need some like this:

```
if(ip1 == ip2)
{
   //true
}
```

Comment: How come the code you just posted dont suit your needs?

Comment: @Luis, because the same IP address can have a different string representation since the numbers can legally be represented in both hex and base 10 notation.

Comment: @Luis: Try this: `ping 2130706433`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It seems System.Net.IPAddress defines it's own Equals override so this should work:

```
IPAddress ip1 = IPAddress.Parse("123.123.123.123");
IPAddress ip2 = IPAddress.Parse("124.124.124.124");

if(ip1.Equals(ip2))
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: @PhucNguyen - `IPAddress.Parse("172.16.0.150").Equals(IPAddress.Parse("172.16.1.216"))` returns false for me as expected.

Answer (score 20):

The type `IPAddress` in the BCL supports equality and can be used for this purpose.

```
public static bool IsSameIPAddress(string ip1, string ip2) {
  IPAddress leftIP = IPAddress.Parse(ip1);
  IPAddress rightIP = IPAddress.Parse(ip2);
  return leftIP.Equals(rightIP);
}
```

Several people have wondered why a straight string comparison is not sufficient.  The reason why is that an IP address can be legally represented in both base 10 and hexidecimal notation.  So the same IP address can have more than 1 string representation.

For example

```
var left = "0x5.0x5.0x5.0x5";
var right = "5.5.5.5";
IsSameIPAddress(left,right); // true
left == right; // false
```

Comment: @JaredPar: `leftIP==rightIP` in your first code would return false for same IP address! It should be `return LeftIP.Equals(rightIP);`

Comment: @KMan, just noticed that myself and updated my post.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: The hex stuff was new to me. Interesting. It also gets worse with IPv6, since you don't *have* to shorten the addresses with `::` there.

Comment: I've never seen *dotted* hex format used.  non-dotted hex yes (0x05050505), but never dotted hex.

Comment: @OMG Unicorns, both forms are legal at least in respect to what `IPAddress.Parse` supports.  I'm not sure about the official IP standard off the top of my head though.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.equals) method on `System.Net.IPAddress`

Answer (score 2):

```
IPAddress addr1 = IPAddress.Parse(ip1);
IPAddress addr2 = IPAddress.Parse(ip2);

return (addr1.Equals(addr2));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `IPAddress` class (System.Net) has an overridden Equals method that will compare the addresses, not the object instances, which is what you want.  String comparison here may be dangerous since it is possible for IP addresses to have more than one string representation.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.equals%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

```
IPAddress.Parse(ip1).Equals(IPAddress.Parse(ip2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class to compare IpAddress :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26550/Extending-the-IPAddress-object-to-allow-relative-c