# How to compare two different IP?

Tags: c#, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [compare two ip with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722598/compare-two-ip-with-c-sharp)

How to compare two IP? By compare I mean to tell whether IP1 is greater that IP2. Is that possible? As I see, `IPAddress` does not have that functionality.

Comment: I tried to compare string representation, but as it turned out, it's not unique.

Comment: well NaNNy provided a solution for equality, but as far as I understood thats not what you need right?

Comment: How do you *want* to define greater than? Addresses from different families have no obvious ordering relationship between them. Why do you need to perform this comparison? Even within a family, comparing two addresses doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: I want to enumerate through IPs as 194.44.44.44,194.44.44.45,...,194.44.44.255,194.44.45.0 and so on

Comment: and greater may be defined as follows: first triplet of IP that is greater than the same triplet in other IP automatically means that IP1 is greater.

Comment: So, is the question you *should* have asked "how do I enumerate a range of IP addresses, given a start address and an end address", or possible "how do I enumerate a subnet"?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you're right.

Comment: try the string compare solution given by me in my answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT** (This might work for all condition which is specified in comments )

```
string ip1= "1.2.3.4";
string ip2 ="5.6.7.8";

string[] ip1S = ip1.Split(new char[] {'.'});
string[] ip2S = ip2.Split(new char[] {'.'});

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
  if(Convert.ToInt32(ip1S[i]) > Convert.ToInt32(ip2S[i]))
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ip1 is higher");
    break;
  }
  else if(Convert.ToInt32(ip2S[i]) > Convert.ToInt32(ip1S[i])) 
   {
    Console.WriteLine("ip2 is higher");
    break;
  }  
}
```

---

Old

you can do string comapre like this

```
string ip1= "1.2.3.4";
string ip2 ="5.6.7.8";

string ip1R = ip1.Replace(".","");
string ip2R = ip2.Replace(".","");


Console.WriteLine(String.Compare(ip1R ,ip2R ));
```

output

```
A negative integer    str1 is less than str2.
0                     str1 equals str2.
A positive integer    This instance is greater than value.
-or-
1
```

For more change string compare on MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbh501kz(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: -1 not by me, this will work, thank you. Looking for easier solution.

Comment: **1)** Typo `stirng ` **2)** Replace takes two parameters **3)** wouldn't work for `1.2.3.45` and `1.2.34.5`

Comment: @L.B thank you that mentioned. Actualy i asked this question because thought there is some built in functionality. string comparison I can implement by myself.

Comment: @L.B - errors are updated now

Comment: This still will say `192.168.1.123` and `192.168.11.23` are the same. _Why are you removing the `.`?_

Comment: @Rawling - hi now updated answer will satisfy the condition for you ...

Comment: @L.B - hi my last update to answer might work for all conditions ...

Comment: You need `else if(Convert.ToInt32(ip1S) < Convert.ToInt32(ip2S))` instead of `else`, or else you only ever consider the first byte.

Comment: @robjb - all thing fixed...also the output of the program ....now it will show correct output

Comment: and what happens if they're equal?

Comment: @robjb - that come out of the loop without printing anything ...i think thats part left for OP what he wants to do right now he asked about which one is greater...

Answer (score 0):

edit: see [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c) for something far more elegant. Heed the warning about endian-ness, though.

<strike>Pranay Rana's answer is fundamentally broken: comparing '11.2.3.4' and '1.12.3.4' will show that they are are equal. They're clearly not.</strike>

IP addresses are essentially 32 bit integers in a particular form. You can use this fact to write a trivial function that takes the string value and gives you the integer, which is easier to compare against:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ip1 = "11.2.3.4";
    string ip2 = "1.12.3.4";
    uint ipInt1 = ipAddressToInt(ip1);
    uint ipInt2 = ipAddressToInt(ip2);
    Console.WriteLine(ipInt1 < ipInt2);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static uint ipAddressToInt(string ip)
{
    uint retVal;
    System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(ip);
    byte[] IPBytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes(); 

    retVal = (uint)IPBytes[3] << 24;
    retVal += (uint)IPBytes[2] << 16;
    retVal += (uint)IPBytes[1] << 8;
    retVal += (uint)IPBytes[0]; 
    return retVal;
}
```

Note the [System.Net.IPAddress.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.parse.aspx) in the ipAddressToInt function.  This validates the input string before working with it.

Comment: hi i updated my answer and it will work the for the condition you given...

Comment: You can't convert strings to longs with `long ip1 = ip1.Replace(".", "");`. If anything, it's even more broken now than before.

Comment: i updated my answer after words you can check it ....check top one which is latest ..

Comment: Ehh. Here's an answer that makes both of ours look terrible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/461742/how-to-convert-an-ipv4-address-into-a-integer-in-c

Comment: I'd disagree with your byte significances here. If you make the fourth byte most significant, you end up e.g. sorting `11.0.0.10` between `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.15`

Comment: (That link in your last comment makes the same mistake - or rather, relies on the host machine's endianness - and also makes the mistake of using a _signed_ `int`, again messing with any sorting you might do.)

Comment: That was exactly my issue, I was running into an endian problem. Assumptions, eh?